# Django send_mail function keeps failing

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to make django send a mail to one user once the user input his email but it keeps failing. For example, user A signup to my list and django sent him a mail. User B signup to my list and django sends both user A and B a mail.

I don't want that kind of process, I want to send a mail to each user once they fill in their email address. So that when another user signup django won't send the current user and the ones already on the database the same mail.

Below are my codes:

## send invitation

```
Subject='Join Me'

message=loader.get_template('letter.txt') 

from_email='test@testing.com'


def invite_me(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
       form=InviteForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          #get input data and send email to the user.
          send_mail(Subject,message.render(Context()),from_email,Invite.objects.values_list('email_address', flat=True))
          return HttpResponse('Thanks For Inputting Your Email, Go Check Your Inbox!')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid Email Address')
      else:
          form=InviteForm()
          return render_to_response('home.html',{'InviteForm':InviteForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using: `Invite.objects.values_list('email_address', flat=True)`, which returns a List of all the `email_address` fields for all the `Invite`s in your database.

This means that `all` the registered `Invite`'s will receive an email.
I assume `InviteForm` is a `ModelForm` for you `Invite` object. [`ModelForm.save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) returns the newly created object, so you should be doing:

```
invite = form.save()
send_mail(Subject,message.render(Context()),from_email,[invite.email_address])
```

Remember that [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) expects an iterable, so using a list here is required, **this is achieved by using `[invite.email_address]` and not just `invite.email_address`.**

Comment: I tried it but I'm getting a TypeError: 'Invite' object is not iterable.  even if I choose to do it like this: Invite.objects.latest('email_address') I will still get the same error. How can I make the list iterable?

Comment: @picomon Two things. First, you probably forgot to add the `[` `]` around the `invite`. Second, I made a mistake, it should be `[invite.email_address]` not `[invite]`. On a sidenote, using `.latest` will expose you to race conditions, and you should avoid it.